# Pure CSS Checkbox without label

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've been looking for a way to easily style checkboxes even in those cases where I don't have labels but I haven't found any answer that completely satisfied me so I decided to try and find a way by myself so that all the others might find it useful.

Comment: Asked 9 mins ago, Answered 9 mins ago!

Comment: @Trix yes, it was an auto-answer, just to inform others who might want to achieve the same result :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up with.

[CSS Checkbox without label](http://codepen.io/Havock94/pen/XKmMKv)

What I do is basically style the after elements and set pointer-events to none so you'll be able to click true the after element.

This allows us to let the checkbox handle the click and change its state from checked to unchecked and we'll then style the after element depending on the checkbox state.

This will be the unchecked style

```
.check:after{
    pointer-events: none;
    background: white;
    content: ...
    ....
}
```

And then we'll have our checked style

```
.check:checked:after{
    background: green; /* Change background and maybe image */
    ....
}
```

Please notice that the original checkbox will be still visible under the after element since we can't hide it (hiding it will end up hiding after and before elements too) so you can't play with transparency on your after element but you can still play with background image position and background color as I did in the example.

I hope this will help you with your styles! :)